# What is the significance of the export keyword when declaring a module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've created a new TypeScript module called `some-js-library` and defined an interface inside it. I've observed that even if I omit the `export` keyword, the interface can still be accessed by others who import from the module.

I'm wondering if it's important to include the `export` keyword when declaring a module, and in what cases it might matter. For example:

```
declare module "some-js-library" {
  export interface Foo {
    bla: boolean;
  }
}
```